# ActionLink with parameter in another controller MVC5

Tags: actionlink, asp.net-mvc-5

Can i create an action link to another controller and the action method takes a parameter?

the ordinary action link is:

@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Table1")

and if we have an actionlink to an action method inside the controller:

@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID })

Now what if i want to go to an action link to an action method inside another controller? What it will look like?

i.e. There is an action method Action1 that takes a parameter ParentID in the contoller Table2
How can i write an action link to this action method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is another [overload of ActionLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29) helper which lets you specify the controller name, action name and the route values.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

So if you want to render a which points to `Table2/Action1`, you ca use that overload

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Action1","Table2", new { ParentID = 100 },null)
```

You can change hardcoded 100 with your actual value.